# Переносы для поддержки flake8

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-style, flake8

У меня есть код: (python3, максимальная длина строки 120)

```
self.command(
        parametr1, parametr2, self.object1(
                                           need_to_be_rewrited=self.need_to_be_rewrited
                                           )
```

Но flake8 выдаёт исключение

```
E501 line too long (122 > 120 characters)
```

Я попробовал перенести код так:

```
self.command(
        parametr1, parametr2, self.object1(
                                           need_to_be_rewrited= \
                                           self.need_to_be_rewrited
                                           )
```

и получил предупреждение flake8:

```
E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

```
self.command(
        parametr1, parametr2, 
        self.object1(
                     need_to_be_rewrited=self.need_to_be_rewrited)
```